# Php checkbox value post to view using codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

post the value of selected checkbox from php form to view in codeigniter framework

php form

```
<input type='checkbox' value="<?php echo $row_id ?>">
<input type='hidden' name='asap[]' value="1 " >
<input type='hidden' name='asap[]' value="2 " >
<input type='hidden' name='asap[]' value="3 " >
```

controller

```
$asap=> $this->input->post('asap')
```

view

```
echo $asap;
```

the value of checkbox does not show in view

Comment: What's the question? `$asap` would be an array(*I think*)

Comment: ohh i forgot about that .. view does not echo the post i input

Comment: `echo $asap[0];` Maybe?

Comment: Undefined index: asap   but i already define it as $this->load-view('view');

Comment: still can't get it here is my full controller
  ```public function view()
    {
  $this->layout->buffer ( 
   array(
    'asap' =>$this->input->post('asap')
   ));
   $this->load->view('view');
    } ```

Comment: First of all, if you want selected checkbox value then you need to add `name` attribute in it, second, if you want to get `asap` values then you need to do echo $_POST['asap'][0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

view:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='cname' value="<?php echo 'cvalue'; ?>">//changes
<input type='hidden' name='asap[]' value="1" >
<!--removed right space from value-->
<input type='hidden' name='asap[]' value="2" >
<!--removed right space from value-->
<input type='hidden' name='asap[]' value="3" >
<!--removed right space from value-->
```

controller:

```
//here you have syntax error use `=` instead `=>`
$postData = $this->input->post();
//you get all your post data, if you added `name` attribute only
print_r($postData);
//it will return you first hidden value
print_r($postData['asap'][0]);
echo '------------';
echo 'loop values';
$asap = $this->input->post('asap');
foreach($asap as $row){
       echo $row.'<pre>';
}
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [cname] => cvalue
    [asap] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1 
            [1] => 2 
            [2] => 3 
        )

)
1
----------
loop values
1
2
3
```

Comment: He is using CodeIgniter :)

Comment: @Eddie, Am i missing something?

Comment: I'm not familiar with CI at all, but I'm pretty sure it has a proper way of getting `post`  data and not the `$data = $_POST`

Comment: ok updated code, i assumed he, read all things from user guide, Thanks @Eddie

Comment: thanks sir i can get the value now but how can i echo them by row ? ```<td><?php echo $asap>``` or ```foreach ($asap as sap) {```the echo 1 by 1 or array by row

Comment: your always welcome, Please kindly accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

you want to get the value of checkbox so you need to put in a array.

In controller

```
public function update() {
   $completed_asap = $this->input->post('asap');
   // No need to echo $completed_asap. If you want then please do below line.
   // var_dump($completed_asap);
   foreach ($completed_asap as $asap_id) {
      echo 'The asap with id = ' . $asap_id. ' is marked as completed.<br>';
   }
}
```

In your view

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple CodeIgniter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Todos</h1>
        <?php echo form_open('controller_name/update'); ?>
            <div class="list-group">
                <?php foreach ($todos as $todo) { ?>
                    <div class="list-group-item clearfix">
                        <?php echo form_checkbox('asap[]', $asap->id, $asap->completed); ?>
                        <?php echo $asap->task; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <?php echo form_close();
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```